# Swift: How can we create number of buttons from number of items in an array?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift

So the number of buttons on screen change with number of items in array from API.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple example, i have an array of integers and for each item in the array i am going to create a UIButton and add it to array of UIButton.

```
let array = [1,2,3,4]

var buttons: [UIButton] = []

for item in array {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.titleLabel?.text = "Button \(item)"
    buttons.append(button)
}

print("Number of buttons: \(buttons.count)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information you should not create a button for each item in the array you collect from an external API. Since you are using a collection view I would design a collection view cell with the appropriate properties. One of the properties should be a unique identifier. This standard collection view cell is the model for all your collection view cells, that represent your buttons.

Then use the collection view delegate method: collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:) to react on a tap/press from the user. In this method the functionality that you use will be based on the unique identifier of your collection view cell.

There is no need to create a button in a collection view. The collection view already has all the functionality in its collection view item.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to create buttons dynamically, so, according to the array, the number of buttons should be created, and their title should be set accordingly.

Comment: Creating the buttons is not so difficult, but placing them in a view is. It is better to be more specific in what you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to get data from an API into an array, and make that array come on screen in a form of buttons, through ui collection view, so that they can be scrolled. I can provide more detailes.

Comment: Hi Ansar, that is quite a lot of programming that you need to do then. You not only need to dynamically create the buttons, but put these buttons in your collection view cell and create an action method for the button which functionality depends on the unique identifier of the button.

Comment: Hi, Ansar I changed my answer, since I don't think your on the right track with your array of buttons in a collection view.